# FF extension : goUpdateCommand not calling the command

Tags: firefox-addon, xul, firefox4

Firefox version : 4.0.1

I have a commandset which fires when something is selected.

The commandset is working fine. If I put a simple window.alert('test'); it does fire. However when I try to call another command using **goUpdateCommand**, it does not call it.

The code in the browserOverlay.xul is as below :

`<command id="cmd_testselect" oncommand="window.alert('command fired');"/>`

`<commandset commandupdater="true"

    events="select"

    oncommandupdate="goUpdateCommand('cmd_testselect');"/>`

**Note :** I have added the globalOverlay.js as below :
`<script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://global/content/globalOverlay.js"/>`

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong ?

Comment: Nevermind. Looked at the code for goUpdateCommand. It just sets the attribute 'disable' and doesn't call the underlying command.

Answer (score 1):

I think you actually meant to call `goDoCommand()` and not `goUpdateCommand()`.